# disabling specific dates from html datepicker jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, datepicker

hey guys i am trying to set a datepicker in my webpage and disable some dates from it so it can't be showing
this is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>

        <link href="jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="jquery-ui/external/jquery/jquery.js" ></script>
        <script src="jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>

        <script>

            /** Days to be disabled as an array */
            var disableddates = ["20-5-2015", "12-11-2014", "12-25-2014", "12-20-2014"];

            function DisableSpecificDates(date) {

                var m = date.getMonth();
                var d = date.getDate();
                var y = date.getFullYear();

                // First convert the date in to the mm-dd-yyyy format 
                // Take note that we will increment the month count by 1 
                var currentdate = (m + 1) + '-' + d + '-' + y;

                // We will now check if the date belongs to disableddates array 
                for (var i = 0; i < disableddates.length; i++) {

                    // Now check if the current date is in disabled dates array. 
                    if ($.inArray(currentdate, disableddates) != -1) {
                        return [false];
                    }
                }
            }

            $(function () {
                $("#date").datepicker({
                    beforeShowDay: DisableSpecificDates
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input id="date" type="text">
    </body>
</html>
```

but it is not working for some reason... the date picker don't even show 
can someone plz help

Comment: Please, post the javascript error that appears on your console. Did you try to use the Developer Tools in Chrome or something similar?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this, run this code below. The first date I added a 0 to the day so that it will match the formatting in the comparison.

```js
/** Days to be disabled as an array */
var disableddates = ["20-05-2015", "12-11-2014", "12-25-2014", "12-20-2014"];


function DisableSpecificDates(date) {
    var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date);
    return [disableddates.indexOf(string) == -1];
  }
  /*
var m = date.getMonth();
var d = date.getDate();
var y = date.getFullYear();

// First convert the date in to the mm-dd-yyyy format 
// Take note that we will increment the month count by 1 
var currentdate = (m + 1) + '-' + d + '-' + y ;

// We will now check if the date belongs to disableddates array 
for (var i = 0; i < disableddates.length; i++) {

// Now check if the current date is in disabled dates array. 
if ($.inArray(currentdate, disableddates) != -1 ) {
return [false];

}
}

}*/


$(function() {
  $("#date").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: DisableSpecificDates
  });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>

  <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <input id="date" type="text">


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this does not even open datepicker

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on Thomas' answer, here I have added `noweekends` functionality to `DisableSpecificDates` function in `PrepareDate`, to use in `beforeShowDay` like: `beforeShowDay:PrepareDate`

```js
function DisableSpecificDates(date) {
    var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date);
    return [disableddates.indexOf(string) == -1];
    }
    function PrepareDate(date){
    if ($.datepicker.noWeekends(date)[0]) {
    return DisableSpecificDates(date);
    } else {
    return $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Disabled Days of the Week**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="height:130px;">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker11'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar">
                    </span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker11').datetimepicker({
                daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6]
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```