# Disable specific dates and disable dates before today

Tags: jquery, css

I have a datepicker with disabled days, which are displayed with red color, when I disable the days before today, they also turn red, the problem is that I only want to red the days in reserve(booking), and place the days before Today disabled but without color.

The Code

```
<?php
    include "controlreservas/conexion.php";
    $id_habitacion=$_POST["buttonValue"];
    $sql1="SELECT llegada,salida,id_reserva FROM reservas where id_habitacion ='$id_habitacion'";
    $query = $con->query($sql1);
    $dates_ar = [];
    if($query->num_rows>0) {
        while ($r=$query->fetch_array()) {
            $begin = new DateTime( $r["llegada"] );
            $end = new DateTime( $r["salida"] );
            $end = $end->modify( '+1 day' ); 
            $interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
            $daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);
            foreach ($daterange as $date) {
            $dates_ar[] = $date->format("Y-m-d");
            }
        }
        ?>
        <script>
        var disabledDates = <?php echo json_encode($dates_ar)?>;
            $(function() {
               var date = new Date();
                $("#datepicker9").datepicker("destroy");
                 $( "#datepicker9").datepicker({
            minDate:0,
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                     beforeShowDay: disableSpecificDates

                });
            });         
function disableSpecificDates(date) {
    var string = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
    return [disabledDates.indexOf(string) == -1];

  }

        </script>
        <?php
    }

    else {
?>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $( "#datepicker9").datepicker({ 
                    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
           });
            });
        </script>
        <?php

    }
?>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
 .ui-datepicker-today a.ui-state-highlight {
        border-color: #000000;
        background: #607D8B ;
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);    
    }
   .ui-datepicker-today.ui-datepicker-current-day a.ui-state-highlight {
        border-color: #000000;
        background: #607D8B;
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    }
.ui-datepicker td.ui-state-disabled>span{background: #FF6C6C;}
.ui-datepicker td.ui-state-disabled{opacity:50;}

</style>
```

result: [image]

Thanks for you time

Comment: Have you tried to set the minDate option to today? http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate  (i haven't tested but it might work)

Comment: Looks like this post may be helpful for disabling particular dates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30331543/disabling-specific-dates-from-html-datepicker-jquery