# Disable some future dates in DateRangePicker

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I'm trying to disable today date and 6 more days dates from today.

I know I can do that with `maxDate` but when I do, it disable all future dates.

My code:

```
  $('input[name="datefilter"]').daterangepicker({
      autoUpdateInput: false,
      maxDate: new Date(),
      "autoApply": true,
      locale: {
        "firstDay": 1,
        "separator": " - "
      }
  });
```

I tried with `maxDate: new Date(6)` too but same error.

Any idea?

Comment: which datepicker you use? can you create a working example? (jsfiddle/codepen/snippet?)

Comment: I use dateranger picker from https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker

Comment: now, once we know the library you use, it's possible to help :) (check my answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `isInvalidDate` function to return `true/false` if the date is valid or not:

```js
invalid_dates = ['2017-01-11', '2017-01-12', '2017-01-13']
$(function() {
  $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
    isInvalidDate: function(date)
    {
      return !!(invalid_dates.indexOf(date.format('YYYY-MM-DD')) > -1);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- Include Required Prerequisites -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3/css/bootstrap.css" />
 
<!-- Include Date Range Picker -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />
<input type="text" name="daterange" value="01/01/2017 - 01/10/2017" />
```

Comment: Good catch! I missed that one when scanning through the options.

Comment: Thanks @krillgar :) I guess the voteup is yours, appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

That's not an error, that's the expected behavior of the property you're using. You're telling it "don't allow any date beyond this". According to the [docs](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#options), there is an option for `isInvalidDate` that Dekel found in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41679516/1195056).

I was about to delete this answer, but decided against it due to pointing out that it wasn't an error, but the behavior of the property that was being used. Anyone should definitely upvote the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41679516/1195056) for finding that property first.

Comment: Thx, but I saw on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30331543/disabling-specific-dates-from-html-datepicker-jquery that it's possible to disable some specific dates. Maybe I can disable using Today+1, today+2 etc.., isn't ?

Comment: That's for a different plugin. It's being called with `.datepicker()` whereas yours is `.daterangepicker()`.