# Disable Tomorrow date in Jquery Datepicker

Tags: php, jquery, datetimepicker

I want to disable only tomorrow date in my Jquery Datepicker. I am able to disable all coming dates but not only Tomorrow date please help me.

Comment: Could you please include your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable selectability of future dates by specifying `0` for the `maxDate` option.

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    maxDate: 0 // 1 for tomorrow, 2 for day-after, and so on..
});
```

For More Details Refer **[Link](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate)**

Comment: This will disable all dates from tomorrow day-after etc not specific date only.

Comment: exactly i want to disable only tomorrow date

Comment: For that You need to add that day in variable and refer this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30331543/disabling-specific-dates-from-html-datepicker-jquery