# Can I set disable holiday and weekend in datepicker jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I wanna set disable for weekend and holiday in jQuery Datepicker. But, the holidays are from my array. I try to create the code like below. What should I do?

```
    $( function() {
    var holidays = ["2017-01-01","2017-01-28","2017-02-15","2017-03-28","2017-04-14"
                    ,"2017-04-24","2017-05-01","2017-05-11","2017-05-25","2017-06-01"
                    ,"2017-06-25","2017-06-26","2017-06-27","2017-06-28","2017-06-29"
                    ,"2017-06-30","2017-08-17","2017-09-01","2017-09-21","2017-12-01"
                    ,"2017-12-25"
    ];
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function(date){

            var datestring = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
            return [ holidays.indexOf(datestring) == -1 ];
        },
        beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
        MinDate : '0',
        changeMonth :true,
        changeYear : true,
        yearRange: "c-40:+c+0"
    });
 } );
```

What should I do? Thanks in advance

Comment: So, I have to check available date before?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30331543/disabling-specific-dates-from-html-datepicker-jquery

Comment: Thanks a lot guys