# Jquery UI Datepicker Show Additional Disabled Dates

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to show additional disabled dates for the datepicker. For instance, I have min date as `2-1-2018` and max date as `3-1-2018`. Is there anyway way to show `1-1-2018` and `4-1-2018` as disabled? Here is what I have right now. I don't need to dynamically set the dates. I need to display additional disabled dates so the user can see a larger range of disabled dates.

```
             beforeShow : function () {

             if (attrs.selecteddate) {
                 /*
                  2018-10-29T00:00:00.000+0000 before
                  2018-10-29 after
                  Only need the 00-00-0000 part of the date to avoid time zone issues. QoT always returns 00T for timezone anyways. 
                 */
                 var formattedDate = attrs.selecteddate.split("T");
                 attrs["formattedDate"] = formattedDate[0].substring(5) + "-" + formattedDate[0].substring(0, 4);
                 /*z
                 Set the date that the calander will display.
                 Append universal date time zone so correct date will be set in Firefox. It replaces T00:00:00.000+0000 with T12:00:00Z
                 */
                 jQuery(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(formattedDate[0] + 'T12:00:00Z')); 
             }

            jQuery(this).datepicker('option', {
               minDate : ( attrs.edittype === 'single' ) ? incrementDate(attrs.mindate) : attrs.mindate,
               maxDate : ( attrs.edittype === 'single' ) ? convertToDateObj(attrs.maxdate) : attrs.maxdate
            });
         },
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [disabling specific dates from html datepicker jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30331543/disabling-specific-dates-from-html-datepicker-jquery)

Comment: start from 1st jan and end as 4th april and disable both dayd

Comment: Post the code you tried please

Comment: try adding some of your efforts in form of the code you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

This below js code will help you to change min and max date dynamically.

```js
$(function(){

$("#fdate").datepicker({
    formatDate:"dd-mm-yy",
    onselect:function(){
      //do stuff here
    },
    onclose:function(){
    //do stuff here
    }
  });
  
var date1 = "15-11-2017";
var date2 = "17-11-2017"; //you can pass dynamically date

$("#fdate").datepicker("option", "minDate", date1);
$("#fdate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", date2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input id="fdate" type="text" name="date" />
```